# Given a word how to find derivationally related word in wordnet

Tags: nlp, wordnet

Suppose a word given like,founder will be  found,owner will be own,writer will be write ,how to do using wordnet.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you have to do is lemmatize the word to its actual word. You have to use nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('word','POStag') to obtain the actual word.

Answer (score 0):

You want to stem your words. The stem of a word is the part of the word without its affix and suffix. This information is not given in WordNet so you have to use something else.

There are several tools. In my team we use for English Snowball (hhttp://snowballstem.org) which implements the Porter algorithm.

You will find more information about stemming, algorithms and tool on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming